# Mkdocs theme 'Material' not working on mac os

Tags: themes, documentation, mkdocs

i have been trying everything to get the Mkdocs theme 'material' to work on Mac os , i tried pip to install it and tried the repository cloning method too but still it does not work, the theme displayed is still default,

i changed the mkdocs.yml file to this

```
theme: 
name: 'material'
```

and this too

```
theme:
name: null
custom_dir: 'mkdocs-material/material'
```

but i still get the default theme

can someone help me with this?
thanx

Comment: How did you install `mkdocs`? To ensure both are installed to the same Python, run `mkdocs --version` and `pip --version`. Both commands will indicate which Python is associated with that command. They should both point to the same Python installation. If not, edit your question and include the results.

Comment: hi, i fixed the issue, it seams like that the issue was installing mkdocs using Brew and material using pip, i have uninstalled everything and i reinstalled them all using pip this time, now everything is working as expected ,

Comment: That is what I expected. Brew uses a weird non-conventional way of installing MkDocs which does not allow any third party themes or plugins to work with it.